# PostgreSQL function lags when passing a date from another table as argument

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I created a function that retrieves data from multiple table and insert the result into a new table. I am passing few dates in the where clause to filter the applicable information. The dates are in timestamptz format. The query takes roughly a min to process. However when I make the change in the where clause to pass the date from another table, the query lags a lot. i.e.

My initial argument that doesn't lag is
where timestamp = '2022-01-05 04:00:00+00'

The lag is when I change this where clause to pass this date from another table.
where timestamp = select date_time from table_Test

The date_time in table_test is defined as timestamptz and the value is '2022-01-05 04:00:00+00'.

Any idea why the query lags when I pass the date argument from another table?

Thanks,

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the complete query you are running and the  [execution plans](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) for the slow and fast version as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan. Please also include complete `create index` statements for all indexes as well.

Comment: In one case you're specifying the value directly, in the other it has to be looked up, maybe even multiple times. Please add [the missing info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74942505/postgresql-function-lags-when-passing-a-date-from-another-table-as-argument#comment132252458_74942505) - without it we can only guess.

Comment: In addition to previous comments about `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` add the content of the function(as text) to your question. I suspect their maybe a more efficient way to build the query.

Comment: Hi, thanks all for the input. I tried running the explain command but had to kill the query at the end due to lag response. I did realized that the lag part is when I run the condition in the where clause for non-index field i.e date_modified (non-index) = select date_time from table_Test. I may run using subset of the query to share the explain portion if that works?

Comment: You can try just the `explain` - without the rest it'll return just what it plans to do, without doing it and collecting the stats along the way. Your table, function and index definitions, plus an estimation of their counts/uniqueness/cardinalities would be of great help, too - it might be immediately obvious what can go wrong just looking at how things are set up. A full **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** is the best because it indirectly describes all relevant parts of your setup. If it's slow but doesn't consume a lot of resources, you could leave it running and add it later.